# pool 'sqerl' failed to start member chef server

Tags: chef-infra

Chef server was running perfectly for one week and then suddenly i encountered this error, after that i am not able to do anything.

```
2018-05-16 22:23:47.623 [error] Unable to start database connection: econnrefused
2018-05-16 22:23:47.623 [error] pool 'sqerl' failed to start member: {error,econnrefused}
2018-05-16 22:23:47.623 [error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.15278.27> with 1 neighbours exited with reason: econnrefused in gen_server:init_it/6 line 344
2018-05-16 22:23:47.623 [error] gen_server <0.15274.27> terminated with reason: econnrefused
2018-05-16 22:23:47.623 [error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.15274.27> with 1 neighbours exited with reason: econnrefused in gen_server:terminate/7 line 826
2018-05-16 22:23:47.623 [error] pool 'sqerl' failed to start member: {error,econnrefused}
2018-05-16 22:23:47.623 [error] gen_server <0.15324.27> terminated with reason: econnrefused
2018-05-16 22:23:47.623 [error] Unable to start database connection: econnrefused
2018-05-16 22:23:47.624 [error] Supervisor pooler_sqerl_member_sup had child sqerl_client started with {sqerl_client,start_link,undefined} at <0.1347.0> exit with reason {empty,[{queue,get,[{[],[]}],[{file,"queue.erl"},{line,183}]},{epgsql_sock,command_tag,1,[{file,"/var/cache/omnibus/opscode-push-jobs-server/src/opscode-pushy-server/opscode-pushy-server/_build/default/lib/epgsql/src/epgsql_sock.erl"},{line,433}]},{epgsql_sock,on_message,2,[{file,"/var/cache/omnibus/opscode-push-jobs-server/src/opscode-pushy-server/opscode-pushy-server/_build/default/lib/epgsql/src/epgsql_sock.erl"},{line,725}]},{epgsql_sock,loop,1,[{file,"/var/cache/omnibus/opscode-push-jo..."},...]},...]} in context child_terminated

2018-05-23 18:37:54.359 [error] Supervisor pooler_sqerl_member_sup had child sqerl_client started with {sqerl_client,start_link,undefined} at <0.10001.0> exit with reason <<"57P03">> in context child_terminated
2018-05-23 18:37:54.359 [error] pool 'sqerl' failed to start member: {error,<<"57P03">>}
2018-05-23 18:37:54.359 [error] Supervisor pooler_sqerl_member_sup had child sqerl_client started with {sqerl_client,start_link,undefined} at <0.10004.0> exit with reason <<"57P03">> in context child_terminated
2018-05-23 18:37:54.360 [error] Supervisor pooler_sqerl_member_sup had child sqerl_client started with {sqerl_client,start_link,undefined} at <0.10007.0> exit with reason <<"57P03">> in context child_terminated
2018-05-23 18:37:54.360 [error] Supervisor pooler_sqerl_member_sup had child sqerl_client started with {sqerl_client,start_link,undefined} at <0.10010.0> exit with reason <<"57P03">> in context child_terminated
2018-05-23 18:37:54.880 [error] Supervisor pooler_sqerl_member_sup had child sqerl_client started with {sqerl_client,start_link,undefined} at <0.10013.0> exit with reason <<"57P03">> in context child_terminated
2018-05-23 18:37:54.881 [error] Supervisor pooler_sqerl_member_sup had child sqerl_client started with {sqerl_client,start_link,undefined} at <0.10016.0> exit with reason <<"57P03">> in context child_terminated
2018-05-23 18:37:54.881 [error] Supervisor pooler_sqerl_member_sup had child sqerl_client started with {sqerl_client,start_link,undefined} at <0.10019.0> exit with reason <<"57P03">> in context child_terminated
2018-05-23 18:37:54.881 [error] Supervisor pooler_sqerl_member_sup had child sqerl_client started with {sqerl_client,start_link,undefined} at <0.10022.0> exit with reason <<"57P03">> in context child_terminated
2018-05-23 18:37:54.881 [error] Supervisor pooler_sqerl_member_sup had child sqerl_client started with {sqerl_client,start_link,undefined} at <0.10025.0> exit with reason <<"57P03">> in context child_terminated
```

When i run `chef-server-ctl status` command. It shows following output

```
-------------------
Internal Services 
-------------------
run: bookshelf: (pid 22813) 1397s; run: log: (pid 5416) 715564s
run: nginx: (pid 22843) 1397s; run: log: (pid 5615) 715559s
run: oc_bifrost: (pid 22891) 1396s; run: log: (pid 5226) 715569s
run: oc_id: (pid 22959) 1396s; run: log: (pid 8260) 20889s
run: opscode-erchef: (pid 22972) 1395s; run: log: (pid 5503) 715563s
run: opscode-pushy-server: (pid 23002) 1394s; run: log: (pid 5335) 700091s
run: redis_lb: (pid 23029) 1394s; run: log: (pid 5608) 715559s
-------------------
External Services 
-------------------
run: opscode-solr4: connected OK to http://10.0.1.86:9200
run: postgresql: connected OK to 10.0.1.86:5432
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/errcodes-appendix.html

> 57P03     cannot_connect_now

Sounds like your Postgres server isn't fully started so connections are being rejected.